# biggest eigenvalue of inverse matrix dependent on original matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I heard somewhere that the biggest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ is reciprocal to the biggest eigenvalue of $A$. In which theorem is this stated? Also, what would be the proof of it?

Also, what happens if we restrict $A$'s entries to be all non-negative or all positive?

Comment: For invertible $A$, $Ax=\lambda x\iff x=\lambda A^{-1}x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra So if the biggest eigenvalue of $A$ is 2, 1/2 may not be the biggest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$?

Comment: For invertible $A$, the above says $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. Your statement is false. You have to worry about signs.  If all eigenvalues were positive, you could say "the biggest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ is the reciprocal of the smallest eigenvalue of $A$".

Comment: czal:  What happens if $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$?  What about $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @DavidMitra Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

*This post is made community wiki in order to remove this question from the "unanswered" list.*

---

As noted by David Mitra in the comments we have for invertible $A$ and an eigenvector $x$ that $Ax=\lambda x\Rightarrow A^{-1}x=\lambda^{-1}x$. Thus, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, then $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$. So, if all eigenvalues are positive then the biggest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ is the reciprocal of the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.